# Is it possible to track devices of users on our device

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, gps

I am working on an App, in which i need to track the device using my App. I have gone through the "Find my friends" App that Apple has offered themselves. But, it asks user's permission if he wants to allow tracking his location.

I studied, an app named "Uber", they clearly track the cabs maneuver around the city. They also show the user, how far is that cab from the user, the possibility that might be here is "Uber" dudes could be using external GPS device and may be interfacing them with the user's device. Since, If I am not wrong.. Apple does not allow tracking devices.

But yet, I am in need to implement that kind of functionality in my App. I was wondering if it is possible ? I am aware of location tracking, my concern here is live GPS tracking.

Please point me in right direction here, Any help with be truly appreciated

Comment: This is possible, you will need a web service to send one users gps data to and send it down to another, monitoring, device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a full working sample that shows how to track android, iphone, windows phone and java me phones. It also has the server software to put the location data in a database and allows you to view the location in real time and also store the routes to view later. Its MIT licensed:

https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/tree/master/phoneClients/android

Comment: Thank you. I will take a loot it later and will let you know here.